# What differences are there between running a command in PHP's shell_exec and in the terminal?

Tags: php, terminal, exec, shell-exec, bitcoin

I'm running into a strange problem where the program being run tries to do something differently depending on whether I run it from Ubuntu's terminal or from shell_exec() or exec(). When I do a "whoami" command on both, I get the same response (my own username), so I can't see it being a user issue.

If you need more specifics, I'm running commands for the Electrum bitcoin client, such as "electrum validateaddress 123". In the terminal, it gives me a JSON string as it's supposed to. In PHP's shell_exec, it throws an error. While debugging the error, I find that it's trying to create a new wallet in "/root/.electrum/", whereas it should be looking in "/home/username/.electrum/". Naturally, it doesn't have permission to create a folder there, so it fails.

So if running a "whoami" in PHP gives me my own username in Ubuntu (which is not the root user), why would it be looking in the root folder?

Comment: cant you define the file path in he php code?

Comment: @Dagon You're right I can, but that didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: then theres another porblem?

Comment: Well, apparently it's somehow a part of the same problem. When I pass the "-w /link/to/wallet" part, it works just fine in the terminal, but throws the same exception when run from PHP. So again, PHP is somehow running the program differently than I am in the terminal. Very strange.